# How to obtain information of a field or variable on the Client side

Tags: acumatica

I am using the *Receipts* page (IN301000) for reference purposes:

I would like to be able to obtain a field's information on the client side with the GetElementByID() method.

When I inspect the field, and identify the rendered ID, I obtain data:

[image]

However, if I refresh the page and invoke the method again, I obtain NULL:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make that information always available?

The final goal here is being able to pass data to the client side. I can - for instance -populate an unbounded field with the FieldSelecting event, and would like to ideally read data out of it.

If there are client variables that could be set from the graph, it would work as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely get `null` because the script is executed in the `top` iFrame instead of the `main` iFrame which contains the control.

The JavaScript global variable `px_alls` contains the editor controls and can be indexed by editor control ID.

```
px_alls["edTransferNbr"].getValue();
document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_form_t0_edTransferNbr_text").value;
```

Script executed in `main` iFrame context:

[image]
When the script is executed in the context of the `top` iFrame you would have to select the `main` iFrame.

```
var mainframe = document.querySelector('[name=main]').contentDocument;
mainFrame.getElementById('ctl00_phF_form_t0_edTransferNbr_text').value;
```

Script executed in `top` iFrame context:

[image]